# Webservice is not working for upload image 1mb size

Tags: php, web-services, file-upload

We are uploading image with webservice, we are encoding that image with base 64 and sending that content in webservice, it is working fine for 500kb, but if file size is more than 500kb then it is not working. What i need to do for that ?
What can be problem ?

Comment: Please post your code as that will allow people to check it for problems.

Comment: Could also possibly be max_upload_size in php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like settings problem:

check upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini

Upload upload_max_filesize is settings of maximum allowed file size and post_max_size is maximum allowed size of post query